# P2pool Crashing after a few minutes

Tags: p2pool

This start today I have reboot the server etc. but doesn't seem to have helped.

Basically it will work for a while then I get a long list of request parent share items.

then the process crashes totally and just loops with

2014-07-09 09:37:33.050000 > ---  ---
2014-07-09 09:37:33.051000 >   File "p2pool\data.pyc", line 431, in attempt_veri
fy
2014-07-09 09:37:33.052000 >
2014-07-09 09:37:33.053000 >   File "p2pool\data.pyc", line 320, in check
2014-07-09 09:37:33.054000 >
2014-07-09 09:37:33.054000 > exceptions.ValueError: share_info invalid
2014-07-09 09:37:33.068000 > Share check failed:
2014-07-09 09:37:33.069000 > Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-07-09 09:37:33.070000 >   File "p2pool\util\deferral.pyc", line 233, in it
2014-07-09 09:37:33.071000 >
2014-07-09 09:37:33.072000 >   File "p2pool\util\deferral.pyc", line 284, in _wo
rker
2014-07-09 09:37:33.072000 >
2014-07-09 09:37:33.073000 >   File "p2pool\node.pyc", line 304, in clean_tracke
r
2014-07-09 09:37:33.075000 >
2014-07-09 09:37:33.076000 >   File "p2pool\data.pyc", line 452, in think
2014-07-09 09:37:33.076000 >
2014-07-09 09:37:33.077000 > ---  ---

I restart p2ool and a few minutes later it is doing it again, I've redownloaded the p2pool files and still happens. am on version 13.4

Comment: Looks like the extended web interface was doing something odd.... reset to the default and it has stopped crashing.

I'd mark this as answered but I'm not allowed apparently...

Comment: The problem here is not stated in a way that it can be reproduced. This question seems unlikely to be relevant to other users.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

resolved now, it was the web interface causing a mass of errors that crashed the system.